# Print one row in multiples rows, depending on a value

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

thanks on advance for your help.

I want to be able to print one row into multiples rows to print labels, example below.

ItemID Descripcion  Qty 
052    Orange Juice 300

I want to print 3 lines of the same row, and the numbers of row will be calculated (in this case) by 100, for example, so I want to print this:

ItemID Descripcion  Qty 
052    Orange Juice 100 
052    Orange Juice 100 
052    Orange Juice 100

But in the order table, I have one line of row.

Thanks for any help, I'm not sure if this is supported.

Comment: You want to print only three rows for each record or multiple rows?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. in this sample above, I can receive 500 divided into 100, then I need to print five lines in other cases. Thanks!

Comment: In Crystal Reports there are sections, Drop the Field in Detail section of the report and you will see the records as they appear in the database table.

Comment: Yes, but they appears as they are in the table, I do not know how to duplicate them, based on a formula result. I mean, there is one line, but I do not know how to make it three, or four, etc.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do that, Either use Push Method of Crystal Reports i.e. Fill the DataSet object (in code) and pass into Crystal Report as DataSource or make Stored Procedure and push the data in temp table as shown here

```
declare @i int;
declare @copies int;
select part_code, description
into #temp
from parts

select * into #temp2 from #temp;

set @i = 1;
while @i < {@copies}
begin
  insert into #temp2 select * from #temp;
  set @i = @i + 1;
end;

select * from #temp2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1. if the max quantity is not too large, you can create multiple sections (Details a, Details b, Details c, ...) and use a dynamic suppress condition to hide the sections beyond the quantity value.

Option 2.  Create a "REPEATER" table with a single column (How_Many) and rows for
1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | ...

Now, in your report, add the REPEATER Table and add a Record Selection condition of

```
{QTY}/100 >= {Repeater.How_Many}
```